# VS Code window gets automatically resized when closing a fullscreen pygame window

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, sdl, sdl-2

I am using the current latest version of VS Code

Version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Python: 3.11.5
Pygame: 2.5.2
i am on windows 11

I am making a fullscreen app in pygame and as the title says whenever i close that program by <kbd>alt+f4</kbd> the VS Code window gets resized to small. the maximize button in the side of the "X" button shows that the window is still maximized.
[image]

Here's some code you can use to reproduce the problem:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

run = 1
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = 0
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Why does this happen? How can I make it not happen?

Comment: I don't see similar behaviour on Windows 10. Maybe [edit] your question to add your python and pygame versions.

Comment: I'm running exactly the same versions of everything and I'm unable to reproduce

Comment: i've tried running in one another device and it still happens, but maybe its device specific problem will try reinstalling vsc

Comment: Why would you reinstall software that's obviously working just fine? Like, an issue with the editor is one of the last things to ever consider. This is a known "issue", it's not really an issue, it's really how the FULLSCREEN flag is sort of intended to work, it changes the monitor resolution or something along those lines, not on all OSs apparently, but majority of the cases. I'd suggest not using the FULLSCREEN flag and instead stick to only using size `(0, 0)`. Or use with `SCALED` flag and a specific resolution.